# Solr docs must match one field

Tags: solr, filter, facet

I have two fields

1. text field .. All important fields like category, product name, brand are copied into it.
2. attributes field .. All attributes are copied into this field.

I have a single search query e.g. "50 mm diameter drill"

I want to search this string in both fields. I am assuming that this will match all products that have drill in the text field.

I want to narrow down the result in case any attributes that match any of 50 mm diameter.

And in case none matches in the attributes field I want to return all documents that match text field.

Edit: I dont want any docs which don't match text field.

I only want that if search is matched to attributes field, and docs are found we return only those docs.

If not found we return all docs which match text field

Answer (score 1):

This is getting a bit tricky and a lot of things depend on your field processing requirements.

You will need to use a combination of field weighting, to rank attributes field higher and edismax minimum match [mm](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29)

Minimum match allows you to configure how many terms in the query must be hit in order for it to display results. This helps weed out documents that only hit on one term in one field.

Lastly, if you really want to have your own logic in here, you can prepend field with + to make it mandatory. For example +attributes:drill will only return items that have drill in the attributes field.

Comment: Please see my other comment not I am getting other problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051388/solr-and-operator-not-working

Comment: No this didnot, I am looking at same problem as this http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/One-field-must-match-with-edismax-td3496232.html

Answer (score 0):

Whether "drill" will match depends on how your fields are processed, but probably, yes. The easiest way to do this is to not limit by "if not matched here, do this ..", but to score matches in the attributes field higher. You can do this by using `qf` (if using (e)dismax) together with their weights, such as `attributes^20 text` which will score any match in attributes 20 times more than a match in text. Any search matching documents with the correct term in `attributes` will then be scored higher than those just matching in `text`.

You can also do something similar in the `q` parameter, where you can weight each term separately: `text:drill OR attributes:drill^20`.

Comment: In this way we will be returned docs which don't match text field due to OR

Comment: Yes, as I explained; those that matches in attributes will be scored higher than those matching in just text. It's hard to say exactly what you want, but you could also use `bq` if you want to use a separate query for boosting documents (allowing `attributes:"50mm diameter"` to boost if there is a match in attributes). You'll have to extend your question with more details if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually I am also faceting on the category on the search results. So I want no results in text field doesnt matches. I created 2 copyfields in one I copied all fields mentioned in text field previously and in 2nd field I coped all fields in text + attribute fields. And now I am doing an AND query but I am getting next problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051388/solr-and-operator-not-working